# Bash compare string and integer together as multi-conditions

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to check current GTK theme and want to check current time, and based on that would like to change the theme as follows:

```
GtkTheme=$(/usr/bin/gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme)
NightTheme="Adapta-Nokto"
DayTheme="Adapta"
TimeHrWithZero=$(date +%H)
TimeHr=$(bc<<<${TimeHrWithZero})
if [ "${GtkTheme}" != "${NightTheme}" ] && if ((${TimeHr}>=19 || ${TimeHr}<=5)); then
    echo ${GtkTheme} ${TimeHr} Night Theme
    /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ${NightTheme}
else
    echo ${GtkTheme} ${TimeHr} Day Theme
    /usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "${DayTheme}"
fi
```

When I remove `if [ "${GtkTheme}" != "${NightTheme}" ] &&` the code works but without that condition. How can I compare with both string and integer comparison together?

Comment: Note, use `date +%_H` (with the underscore) -- hours "08", "09" will result in  arithmetic errors due to bash interpreting numbers with leading 0 as octal, and 8 and 9 are invalid octal digits: `bash: ((: 09: value too great for base (error token is "09")` -- the date format `%_H` uses a space to pad the hour instead of a zero.

Comment: @glennjackman I used this `TimeHr=$(bc<<<${TimeHrWithZero})` to solve that issue.

Comment: Right. I missed that. But an unnecessary call to bc.

Comment: @glennjackman Oh! How to use it without bc?

Comment: As I commented: `TimeHr=$(date +%_H)`. You could also use parameter expansion to remove a leading zero: `TimeHr=$(date +%H); TimeHr=${TimeHr#0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
if [ "${GtkTheme}" != "${NightTheme}" ] && ((${TimeHr}>=19 || ${TimeHr}<=5)); then
```

without the second `if` in between the conditions. The condition in an `if` statement is a compound command, which can include additional `if`s, which is probably what's causing the problem here.

Example:

```
if true && if true; then false; fi; then echo foo; else echo bar; fi
```

is grouped as

```
if (true && (if true; then false; fi)); then echo foo; else echo bar; fi
```

Here, I'm using `()` to show the grouping, not to indicate subshells.